# R .Call hangs with larger dataset

Tags: c, r

I'm converting an R function to C to speed up its runtime. The function in C gets called from R using .Call and works great. However, when I supply a large dataset, it stalls. I placed a simple print statement in the very beginning of the C code, and that statement never gets printed, leading me to believe that it's not that the C code is chugging through the large dataset and just taking time to complete, but that it is unable to get going in the first place. 
The R-only version of this function does successfully handle the large dataset, but takes ~40 minutes.

Is there an object size limit to what can be passed to C through .Call? Why can R handle this volume of data, but not .Call?

I've been able to recreate the problem with dummy input data for R:
When datsize is 1300, the function works. When datsize is 13000 (about the size of my large dataset), the function stalls.

```
datsize <- 1300
# datsize <- 13000
dyn.load('loopRateMatrixThroughTimev2.so')

es1 <- round(runif(datsize, 0, 14000), 0)
es2 <- runif(datsize, 0, 200)
es3 <- runif(datsize, 0, 200)
es4 <- round(runif(13000, 0, 30), 0)
time <- runif(70, 0, 120)
lam1 <- runif(70, 0.1, 3)
lam2 <- runif(70, 0.1, 3)
mu1 <- runif(70, 0.1, 3)
tvec <- runif(100, 1, 100)
node <- -1
nodeset <- round(runif(datsize, 1, 14000), 0)
tol <- 1e-10

res <- .Call('loopRateThroughTimeMatrix', as.integer(es1), es2, es3, as.integer(es4), time, lam1, lam2, mu1, tvec, as.integer(node), as.integer(nodeset), tol)
```

The c code and compiled .so file can be downloaded here:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/34644229/cCode.zip

Any advice would be much appreciated! Thank you.

Sorry, should have mentioned that I am running R 3.0.2 on Mac OS X 10.9.

Comment: Works fine for me in R-3.0.2 (2013-09-25) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit).  Also, the .so file generally won't be useful unless people are running the same OS as you (which you haven't stated).

Comment: There is a _MACOSX folder in there.  My guess is windows! Or linux.  But there is no other possibility.